# Exclude rows where two columns BOTH have a value of zero, not one or the other

Tags: sql

In SQL, I have two interger columns and I want to exclude rows where BOTH columns have a value of zero.

So in the below example, I would want rows 2 and 3 excluded only.

```
    Col 1   Col 2 
1   0.00    1.53 
2   0.00    0.00 
3   0.00    0.00 
4   6.84    0.00
```

I have tried the below to test if it brings me just rows where one column holds 0.00 but the other does not, and there are no rows. Which means, my first argument is not working.

```
WHERE
        (COL1 > 0.00 AND COL2 > 0.00)
        AND (COL1 = 0.00
        OR COL2 = 0.00)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where *specifically* are you getting stuck? Questions on Stack Overflow are generally expected to illustrate a good-faith attempt on the part of the asker before posting here. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How would you write it if you wanted one or the other?

Comment: Col 1 > 0 and Col 2 > 0 but I need it wrapped up, so it's looking at them inclusively. 
If I did 
<WHERE
         Col 1 > 0.00
AND Col 2 > 0.00/>
That would remove all rows where either are zero not both.

Comment: `where not (col1 = 0 and col2 = 0)`. By DeMorgan this is equivalent to `where col1 <> 0 or col2 <> 0`

Comment: But when I test it by looking for where col 1 = 0.00 or col 2 = 0.00, I am getting no rows which means it's excluding all rows which are zero, not just where both are

Comment: @Jemma . . . You want `OR` not `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `AND` with a `NOT` to filter results so that if both columns contain 0, they are filtered:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NOT(col1 = 0 AND col2 = 0)
```

If you want numbers to appear that have NO `0` in them such as a row: `12,12` the ***Exclusive OR*** `XOR` / `<>` will **not** work.

Your best practice is to use the `WHERE NOT` example I have listed.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is best to include example code showing what you have tried along with what is happening versus what you expect to happen. Based on the wording of this question it looks like all you would need in your `WHERE` clause is something like this. If this doe snot answer your question please be more specific as to why and what you have tried.

Proposed `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE

  -- This is going to only include rows
  -- where one or both column values are non-zero
  Col1 <> 0 
  OR Col2 <> 0
```